# Simple verification: is this equivalence always true?

Tags: optimization, equivalence-relations

I have a constrained optimization problem and I am trying to reduce the number of contraints and am afraid to be losing information by doing so. If we have two constraints as the following $$A \geq B \mbox{ and } C \geq D $$  Is it equivalent to write: $$ A + C \geq B + D $$
It is clear that $ A \geq B \Rightarrow A + C \geq B + C \geq B + D \Rightarrow A + C \geq B + D$.
Does the implication work the other way round (it seems to me that the answer is yes)? If not, can you think of a counter example?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No. An example:
$$5+2\geq 1+4$$
where $A=5, B=1, C=2, D=4$.
$C$ is not greater than or equal to $D$.

Comment: But this works no  ( addition is commutative) ? set A=5, B= 4, C=2 and D = 1. We have A > B and C > D , and A + C > B +D.

Comment: @Sha: I edited. If you want the inequality to be true, it has to be true for all numbers. So you cannot just choose your $A,B,C,D$ to make it true.

Answer (score 1):

It is not equivalent. Obviously the first two inequalities prove the second, but this doesn't work in the opposite direction.